# Why is my ContentDialog in WinUI 3 displaying empty even though my XAML has a TextBox in it?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui-3, winui

**WinUI 3 with C#:**

I have my app's main `Window` class that displays a simple dialog when a menu is clicked:

```
private async void MyMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
    {
        XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot,
        Title = "My Dialog",
        Content = new MyContentDialog(),
        PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
        CloseButtonText = "Cancel"
    };
    ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

This is the code-behind for the `MyContentDialog` class:

```
namespace myapp
{
    public sealed partial class MyContentDialog : ContentDialog
    {
        public MyContentDialog()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML for the `MyContentDialog` class:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="myapp.MyContentDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:myapp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

Seems pretty basic, right? So why is my dialog appearing like this with no `TextBox` in it? It doesn't matter what UI controls I add to the XAML, I can't get anything to appear. **Why?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already setting the `Content` here:

```xml
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="myapp.MyContentDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:myapp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Style="{StaticResource DefaultContentDialogStyle}">

    <!-- Content -->
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
    </Grid>

</ContentDialog>
```

So, you are overriding the `Content` here. You just need to remove the code setting the `Content`.

```cs
MyContentDialog dialog = new()
{
    XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot,
    Title = "My Dialog",
    //Content = new MyContentDialog(), 
    PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
    CloseButtonText = "Cancel"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

User **Andrew KeepCoding** led me in the right direction with his partial answer, but here is the fully corrected code.

I needed to call the `MyContentDialog` class as a dialog directly, remove the `Content = new MyContentDialog()` line, and add a line to update the style to look like the default style.

```
MyContentDialog dialog = new MyContentDialog()
{
    XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot,
    Style = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultContentDialogStyle"] as Style,
    Title = "My Dialog",
    PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
    CloseButtonText = "Cancel"
};
ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: I didn't notice that it was ``ContentDialog`` when I copied your code for my answer. Sorry.  BTW, you can set the default style on XAML. See my updated answer.